# Unable to access GPIOs on Intel Alder Lake CPU

Tags: linux, intel, x86, gpio

I have a motherboard with an Alder Lake CPU on it (i9-12900E). I'm trying to access the GPIO pins on the motherboard using [libgpiod](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/about/).

After I boot linux, I have no `/dev/gpiochipX` entries. When I run `gpiodetect` I get no output.

I can see the following in `dmesg`:

```
[    1.389872] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
```

I see the following in [DebugFS](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/debugfs.html):

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio 

# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/pinctrl-devices 
name [pinmux] [pinconf]

# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/pinctrl-handles 
Requested pin control handlers their pinmux maps:

# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/pinctrl-maps 
Pinctrl maps:
```

I have Alder Lake pinctrl support compiled into my kernel:

```
# zgrep -i PINCTRL_ALDERLAKE /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_PINCTRL_ALDERLAKE=y
```

So pinctrl is being initialized, but somehow the pins aren't getting detected. What else can I try to dig deeper into this issue?

For reference I'm running linux kernel version `6.5.2-artix1-1`.